# Usb 3G, 4G modems, power supply

Tags: usb, gsm, modem

I have read that usually a gsm module requires a power supply capable to provide up to 2A. But how can 3g modems sticks work properly when they are powered through usb port which provides only up to 1A(?)

Comment: They only require high current in intermittent bursts. Capacitors solve that problem.

Comment: But capacitors need to refresh their energy in between of each burst.

Comment: Yes - and they do - between the gsm module's high-current bursts, the caps recharge.

Comment: Is this time enough for a capacitor to restore its energy?

Comment: Well, yes. After all, the devices do work.

Comment: This is a fairly interesting question indeed.  The serial interfaced modules are popularly thought to be such power hogs that most writeups end up using a battery even when they have a power supply, rather than trying to do it with caps.  Would be interesting to know what the capacitance on the USB ones is.

Comment: Another possibility is that the dongles use newer signalling modes that simply don't demand as much power.  Experientially, old GSM phones used to really "thump" nearby speakers (especially right before they were about to ring, to the point where that became my effective ringtone), but modern ones don't.  The UART modules are often old 2G designs, while the dongles are more oriented towards achieving useful data speeds.

Comment: GSM used to be TDMA, and the rather high powered transmit bursts would couple in to all sorts of stuff and get peak detected, causing those distinctive sounds. Newer protocols are not TDMA, though they can still transmit with up to 1W of power if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [very related question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/31083/117785).  This modem has 25% duty cycle, so 2A peak translates into 500 mA average. And yes, the voltage drops noticeably when RF transmits, so certain care must be taken to bypass this drop. Other people indicate the amount low-ESR ceramic caps of the order of 2,000 uF, some recommendations go up to 12,000 uF.

Obviously, for the bus-powered USB dongle to meet inrush current requirements, a special gradually-working power management is needed.